# Luigi: how to pass arguments to dependencies using luigi.build interface?

Tags: python, etl, pipeline, luigi

Consider a situation where a task depends on another through a dynamic dependency:

```
import luigi
from luigi import Task, TaskParameter, IntParameter

class TaskA(Task):
    parent = TaskParameter()
    arg = IntParameter(default=0)
    def requires(self):
        return self.parent()
    def run(self):
        print(f"task A arg = {self.arg}")

class TaskB(Task):
    arg = IntParameter(default=0)
    def run(self):
        print(f"task B arg = {self.arg}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    luigi.run(["TaskA", "--parent" , "TaskB", "--arg", "1", "--TaskB-arg", "2"])
```

(Notice the default `arg=0` Parameter).

Using the `luigi.run()` interface, this works. As you can see, `TaskA` is given two arguments: `parent=TaskB` and `arg=1`. Furthermore `TaskB` is also given argument `arg=2` by using the syntax `--TaskB-arg`.

```
Scheduled 2 tasks of which:
* 1 ran successfully:
    - 1 TaskB(arg=2)
* 1 failed:
    - 1 TaskA(parent=TaskB, arg=1)

This progress looks :( because there were failed tasks

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```

(In this example tasks failed because `TaskB` is not writing its output to a file that `TaskA` can read. But that's just to keep the example short. The important point is that both `TaskA` and `TaskB` are passed the correct `arg`).

My problem now is: how do I do the exact same thing, but using the `luigi.build()` interface? There's two reasons why I want to do this: First is that [the source code says](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/luigi/interface.html#run) that `luigi.run()` shouldn't be used. But second, I can't run more than one `luigi.run()` per process, but I can do so with `luigi.build()`. This is important because I want to do something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        luigi.run(["TaskA", "--parent" , "TaskB", "--arg", f"{i}", "--TaskB-arg", f"{i}"])
```

However if you try this you get the error:

`Pid(s) {10084} already running`

So, in the `luigi.build()` interface you're supposed to pass it a list of the tasks instantiated with their parameters:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        luigi.build([TaskA(parent=TaskB, arg=i)])
```

This does what's expected with regards to `TaskA`, but `TaskB` takes the default `arg=0`.

So question: how to pass arguments to dependencies using `luigi.build()` interface?

Here's things that I've tried and don't work:

A)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        luigi.build([TaskA(parent=TaskB, arg=i), TaskB(arg=i)])
```

Doesn't work because two instances of `TaskB` are ran: one with the default (wrong) arg, which `TaskA` depends on, and one with the correct arg, which `TaskA` doesn't depend on.

B)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        luigi.build([TaskA(parent=TaskB(arg=i), arg=i)])
```

`TypeError: 'TaskB' object is not callable`

C)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        luigi.build([TaskA(parent=TaskB, arg=i)], "--TaskB-arg", f"{i}")
```

Getting desperate. I tried something like the old interface, but doesn't work:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'create_remote_scheduler'`

Comment: you have posted 2 questions now and both are exceptional documentation of the question. Kudos to you. Upvoted both.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is that you are passing the parent as a class and not a Task object. Try to pass it like this:

```
luigi.build([TaskA(parent=TaskB(arg=i), ...)])
```

Edit: You may then need to modify `TaskA` because you have

```
def requires(self):
   return self.parent()
```

which constructs the parent as a `TaskB` object with default params.

Edit2: This design model is actually not encouraged. If you are running with multiple workers, then this will not pickle-depickle correctly. I would recommend creating a new `ParameterizedTaskParameter` (or some better name) that pickles a task instance and stores it as an object parameter does.

Comment: That is literally one of the things I tried on my question, see option B)

Comment: No, it's not. You need to not call the made task in the `requires` of A if you fully construct `TaskB` in the constructor of `A`.

Comment: Hm. I see, you're right. Indeed, if we don't construct `self.parent` before returning it, then it works. However, that raises the question: when should or shouldn't you construct the task before returning it from `requires`? If you look at the examples, they always do https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#task-requires which makes sense because you can't depend on an abstract task, you can only depend on a task with specific parameters. So I'm guessing that your suggestion works for this simple case but would go wrong in more complex cases?

Comment: As you seem to be quite knowledgeable of Luigi's intricacies, would you have a look at this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64958830/luigi-how-to-pass-different-arguments-to-leaf-tasks @iHowell