# Luigi: how to pass different arguments to leaf tasks?

Tags: python, etl, pipeline, luigi

This is my second attempt at understanding how to pass arguments to dependencies in Luigi. The first one was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64837259/luigi-how-to-pass-arguments-to-dependencies-using-luigi-build-interface).

The idea is: I have `TaskC` which depends on `TaskB`, which depends on `TaskA`, which depends on `Task0`. I want this whole sequence to be exactly the same always, except I want to be able to control what file `Task0` reads from, lets call it `path`. Luigi's philosophy is normally that each task should only know about the Tasks it depends on, and their parameters. The problem with this is that `TaskC`, `TaskB`, and `TaskA` all would have to accept variable `path` for the sole purpose of then passing it to `Task0`.

So, the solution that Luigi provides for this is called [Configuration Classes](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#configuration-classes)

Here's some example code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import luigi
from luigi import Task, TaskParameter, IntParameter, LocalTarget, Parameter

class config(luigi.Config):
    path = Parameter(default="defaultpath.txt")

class Task0(Task):
    path = Parameter(default=config.path)
    arg = IntParameter(default=0)
    def run(self):
        print(f"READING FROM {self.path}")
        Path(self.output().path).touch()
    def output(self): return LocalTarget(f"task0{self.arg}.txt")

class TaskA(Task):
    arg = IntParameter(default=0)
    def requires(self): return Task0(arg=self.arg)
    def run(self): Path(self.output().path).touch()
    def output(self): return LocalTarget(f"taskA{self.arg}.txt")

class TaskB(Task):
    arg = IntParameter(default=0)
    def requires(self): return TaskA(arg=self.arg)
    def run(self): Path(self.output().path).touch()
    def output(self): return LocalTarget(f"taskB{self.arg}.txt")

class TaskC(Task):
    arg = IntParameter(default=0)
    def requires(self): return TaskB(arg=self.arg)
    def run(self): Path(self.output().path).touch()
    def output(self): return LocalTarget(f"taskC{self.arg}.txt")
```

(Ignore all the `output` and `run` stuff. They're just there so the example runs successfully.)

The point of the above example is controlling the line `print(f"READING FROM {self.path}")` without having tasks A, B, C depend on `path`.

Indeed, with Configuration Classes I can control the `Task0` argument. If `Task0` is not passed a `path` parameter, it takes its default value, which is `config().path`.

My problem now is that this appears to me to work only at "build time", when the interpreter first loads the code, but not at run time (the details aren't clear to me).

So neither of these work:

A)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        config.path = f"newpath_{i}"
        luigi.build([TaskC(arg=i)], log_level="INFO")

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 4 tasks of which:
* 4 ran successfully:
    - 1 Task0(path=defaultpath.txt, arg=2)
    - 1 TaskA(arg=2)
    - 1 TaskB(arg=2)
    - 1 TaskC(arg=2)

This progress looks :) because there were no failed tasks or missing dependencies

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

B)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        luigi.build([TaskC(arg=i), config(path=f"newpath_{i}")], log_level="INFO")

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 5 tasks of which:
* 5 ran successfully:
    - 1 Task0(path=defaultpath.txt, arg=2)
    - 1 TaskA(arg=2)
    - 1 TaskB(arg=2)
    - 1 TaskC(arg=2)
    - 1 config(path=newpath_2)

This progress looks :) because there were no failed tasks or missing dependencies

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```

This actually makes sense. There's two `config` classes, and I only managed to change the `path` of one of them.

Help?

EDIT: Of course, having `path` reference a global variable works, but then it's not a Parameter in the usual Luigi sense.

EDIT2: I tried point 1) of the answer below:

`config` has the same definition

```
class config(luigi.Config):
    path = Parameter(default="defaultpath.txt")
```

I fixed mistake pointed out, i.e. `Task0` is now:

```
class Task0(Task):
    path = Parameter(default=config().path)
    arg = IntParameter(default=0)
    def run(self):
        print(f"READING FROM {self.path}")
        Path(self.output().path).touch()
    def output(self): return LocalTarget(f"task0{self.arg}.txt")
```

and finally I did:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        config.path = Parameter(f"file_{i}")
        luigi.build([TaskC(arg=i)], log_level="WARNING")
```

This doesn't work, `Task0` still gets `path="defaultpath.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

So what you're trying to do is create tasks with params without passing these params to the parent class. That is completely understandable, and I have been annoyed at times in trying to handle this.

Firstly, you are using the `config` class incorrectly. When using a Config class, as noted in https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#configuration-classes, you need to instantiate the object. So, instead of:

```
class Task0(Task):
    path = Parameter(default=config.path)
    ...
```

you would use:

```
class Task0(Task):
    path = Parameter(default=config().path)
    ...
```

While this now ensures you are using a value and not a `Parameter` object, it still does not solve your problem. When creating the class `Task0`, `config().path` would be evaluated, therefore it's not assigning the reference of `config().path` to `path`, but instead the value when called (which will always be `defaultpath.txt`). When using the class in the correct manner, luigi will construct a `Task` object with only `luigi.Parameter` attributes as the attribute names on the new instance as seen here: https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/task.py#L436

So, I see two possible paths forward.

1.) The first is to set the config path at runtime like you had, except set it to be a `Parameter` object like this:

```
config.path = luigi.Parameter(f"newpath_{i}")
```

However, this would take a lot of work to get your tasks using `config.path` working as now they need to take in their parameters differently (can't be evaluated for defaults when the class is created).

2.) The much easier way is to simply specify the arguments for your classes in the config file. If you look at https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/task.py#L825, you'll see that the `Config` class in Luigi, is actually just a `Task` class, so you can anything with it you could do with a class and vice-versa. Therefore, you could just have this in your config file:

```
[Task0]
path = newpath_1
...
```

3.) But, since you seem to be wanting to run multiple tasks with the different arguments for each, I would just recommend passing in args through the parents as Luigi encourages you to do. Then you could run everything with:

```
luigi.build([TaskC(arg=i) for i in range(3)])
```

4.) Finally, if you really need to get rid of passing dependencies, you can create a `ParamaterizedTaskParameter` that extends `luigi.ObjectParameter` and uses the pickle of a task instance as the object.

Of the above solutions, I highly suggest either 2 or 3. 1 would be difficult to program around, and 4 would create some very ugly parameters and is a bit more advanced.

Edit: Solutions 1 and 2 are more of hacks than anything, and it is just recommended that you bundle parameters in `DictParameter`.

Comment: 2) doesn't work in a loop, as far as i can tell, right?. 3) `arg` is secondary to my question, it was just an example. The real problem is passing `path` to the leaf task. 1) i don't really understand. In your example, is config still a Task? Am I meant to not do the `config().path` instantiation then?

Comment: You are correct that 2 does not work in a loop. In 3 I was using arg generically. It could be your path. The point is that you would loop over all possibles values of the argument and create a TaskC with each of them, passing in the argument. You should not do the `config().path` instantiation. It goes against how Luigi works and will not work for your use case.

Comment: Ok, but my point is precisely that I don't want all tasks to know about the path that must be passed to `Task0`. What if I have 100 tasks? Do I have to add something they don't depend on to each of them, just so they can pass it to the next one? That seems like a huge design flaw. There must be a solution to this, this isn't an obscure requirement, right?

Comment: BTW I also edited the original question where I describe that I can't get option 1) to work (or I misunderstood it).

Comment: I'm not sure that 1) would work. You are trying to go against the Luigi paradigm, and that isn't a good idea. The way to programatically change arguments is to programatically change arguments by passing them in.

Comment: Ok cool, I accept that. If you add at the top "you shouldn't use Luigi like this, but here's how you can kind of hack it...." I'll mark your answers as correct (this and the other one) So next question: Given that defining a long chain of operations and passing many different "entry datasets" to those chained operations is a major use-case of mine, do you want to suggest a Luigi-like library that supports that use-case? Airflow supports that, but not dynamic task generation. Prefect supports both but it's oriented towards passing results in memory (as opposed to caching to disk like Luigi).

Comment: I still think that Luigi could be useful. You can always bundle a bunch of parameters together in a `DictParameter` which will cut down on passing many parameters around.